Number of microstates with energy $\leq E$
According to the book Statistical Physics by Franz Mandl, the number of microstates with energy $\leq E$ is of the form $$\Phi(E) = CE^{v}$$ , where $C$ is a constant and $v$ is the number of degrees of freedom. Assuming each particle can adopt only one of the two possible energy states ($x$ or $y$) then $$\Phi(E) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^{n}$$ (the generalization to multinomial states is trivial). In this case $n$ would be $E$ (total energy - i.e. $n$ up arrows -> $E=n$) and $2$ (or $a$ if following a multinomial distribution) would be $v$ (degrees of freedom in system).
Which concepts am I confusing here?

I don't have the book but it seems false in general. Take for example the ideal gas in 3D p.19 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/s12/lecture-notes/chapter04.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj7pZ_g35yGAxV5UqQEHYbpA0gQFnoECDAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0QvffQJ74TfSBT-PPOg-QC the number of state below $E$ is proportional to $E^{3N/2}$. And a ideal gas in 3D has 3 x N (thermodynamic) degrees of freedom.

But perhaps I can be more helpful, it seems that the confusion come from the definition of a degree of freedom. In your case for example, where you state that a particle can take two values $x$ and $y$. This does not really tells us anything about degrees of freedom. A degree of freedom, is a variable that can take some values, that can vary independently on some other variable in the system and that describe a particular thing in your system. For example, if we want to describe a system with an unique particle, we will need 3 variables to specify its speed and 3 to specify its position

However, since its is non interacting  for thermodynamics, we do not really care about its position, hence we say that it has 3 degrees of freedom. Now, if you take 2 particles connected by a spring, we'll  technically, you need 2x3 positions and 2x3 speed, but you might just be fine with 2x3 speed and 3 values for the distance separating the two particles, because it is all that counts for the thermodynamics. Let's say that you somehow fix the total energy of the system, then you should count 1 degree of freedom less that the usual, because you are constraining your system.

All in all, this is more an intellectual game than a counting game concerning the number of variable you want to use (and are needed) to describe the thermodynamics of the system. In your case for example, x and y might just be aswell the value taken by 1 variable describing only 1 degree of freedom (a spin for example). But in any case, I think you should not bother too much with the assertion of Mandl. I think it is not true and on top of that  maybe only relevant for non interacting systems..
